# Azure Service Bus Connection String in KeyVault

Tags: c#

Currently, I have the connection string as an application setting. Instead, I want to be able to use a key vault service to get the connection string and add it in directly.

E.g

```
_keyVault.GetValue("keyvaulturl", "connectionStringKey")
```

Where its used:

```
public async Task Process([ServiceBusTrigger(Connection = "connectionString")]Message message,
           MessageReceiver messageReceiver,
           string lockToken,
           ExecutionContext context)
        {

}
```

How can I refactor this to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See key vault references.

Put this in the config file:
"connectionString": "@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://myvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/mysecret/)"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references?tabs=azure-cli